Use the page title for HTML file name when downloaded using wget
I can download a single stand alone HTML file with:
wget https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/articles/c99rgj0xkryo

but wget will save the file as index.html rather than Nation falls silent as King leads Remembrance ceremony.html. How do I get wget to use the page title?
In this case, I am not concerned with breaking links for the offline files. I am only concerned with downloading stand alone pages.
I am on:

Windows 11
pwsh 7.4


The question is inconsistent - you're asking about page title, but your example shows random (last path?) part of URL. Please clarify what exactly is meant with a better example.

@Destroy666 BBC news articles have URLs of the form https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/articles/crmz42pjpnjo, so the OP appears to be looking to use the <title> element for the name of the file. Which of course may contain characters which are awkward for the file system.

@Destroy666, pardon me, I clarified my example using the most recent article on the bbc site (as of right now) as an example.

On what system? Scripting is almost definitely required.

@Destroy666 I have updated my question.

With PowerShell 5 it's much simplier to get the title:
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/articles/c99rgj0xkryo).ParsedHtml.title

However, ParsedHtml has been basically removed from PowerShell 7 as the requests always use -UseBasicParsing. So you need to use external library or workarounds until they maybe reimplement it.
Then, to clean file names, there're some helper functions to cover all characters, e.g. GetInvalidFileNameChars() that can be used in a function like this:

Function Remove-InvalidFileNameChars {
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
 )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  return ($Name -replace $re)
}


Source.

The flag is -O on wget.
wget -O "Nation falls silent as King leads Remembrance ceremony.html" https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/articles/c99rgj0xkryo


Here's a script to automatically use the title for the file name.
You'll need https://www.html-tidy.org.  It's on the repository for most distributions.
#!/bin/bash

url="$1"

wget -O "temp_index.html" "$url"

tidy -m "temp_index.html"

title_data=$(grep "<title" "temp_index.html" | head -20 | cut -d'>' -f2-)

if [[ "$title_data" =~ "</title>" ]]; then
    title_data=$(echo "$title_data" | sed 's/........$//')
fi

mv "temp_index.html" "$title_data".html

exit 0

After a few tests, I noticed the formatting of the page results in </title> being on the next line, but sometimes it's not. So, I added a check to handle both scenario's.
Save as: html_to_title.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x html_to_title.sh
Usage: ./html_to_title.sh www.example.com

I have not used Windows for so long that this might be outdated, and I have no way to test it, but here's an attempted powershell version.
param (
    [string]$url
)

$tempFile = "temp_index.html"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $tempFile

# Pretty print HTML... Can windows use tidy for this?
$content = Get-Content -Path $tempFile -Raw
$cleanContent = $content

# Compacted HTML will not work, somehow you must use $cleanContent for beautification

Set-Content -Path $tempFile -Value $cleanContent

$titleData = ($cleanContent -match '<title(.*?)</title>') ? $matches[1] : "Untitled"

# Sanitize title for filename, if missed characters, add them here
  
$titleData = $titleData -replace '[<>:"/\\|?*]', '_'  
$newFileName = "$titleData.html"
Rename-Item -Path $tempFile -NewName $newFileName

exit 0

Usage: .\Get-PageTitle.ps1 "http://example.com"
That's the best I can do when it comes to Windows.
